# Tokenize a string keeping inside quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tokenize

I have the following string:

`"'string' 4 '['RP0', 'LC0']' '[3, 4]' '[3, '4']'"`

I am using shlex.split to tokenize the string as following:

```
for element in shlex.split("'string' 4 '['RP0', 'LC0']' '[3, 4]' '[3, '4']'"):
    print(element)
```

And here is the output:

```
string
4
[RP0, LC0]
[3, 4]
[3, 4]
```

But I am looking for the following output:

```
string
4
['RP0', 'LC0']
[3, 4]
[3, '4']
```

Is this doable?

Comment: FWIW it's possible if you nest the quotes: `"'string' 4 '[\"RP0\", \"LC0\"]' '[3, 4]' '[3, \"4\"]'"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know think any library such as shlex would be that flexible, and a regex wouldn't be simple I think, I prefer avoiding somen nested regex.

So we can try it in a relatively simple way in pure python, but it's far from a pythonic answer:

```
myInput = "'string' 4 '['RP0', 'LC0']' '[3, 4]' '[3, '4']'"
processedInput = ""
word_iterator = myInput.__iter__()
for idx, char in enumerate(word_iterator):
    if char == "'":
        continue

    processedInput+=char

    if char == '[':
        next_char=word_iterator.__next__()
        while(next_char != "]"):
          processedInput+=next_char
          next_char=word_iterator.__next__()
        else:
          processedInput+=next_char
```

OUTPUT

```
string 4 ['['RP0', 'LC0']] [3, 4] [3, '4']
```